# Load jQuery file if window width is between values

Tags: jquery, file, load, window, width

I found a lot of solutions but got none of them working..

What I have is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() > 480) {

    }
});
```

What I want to know is how can I load an external js file into my html head when the window width is greater than 480px but smaller than 768px. I tried with 'load' and 'write' but got none of it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() > 480 && $(window).width() < 768) {
        $.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
          console.log( data ); // Data returned
          console.log( textStatus ); // Success
          console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
          console.log( "Load was performed." );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I replace "ajax/test.js" with "js/jquery.zoom.js" it doesn't work. But when i place the direct link: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zoom.js"></script> it does work.. (all time ofcourse instead of between window widths..)

Comment: You said you'd want to load an external file? The URL must be relative to the html document executing the code

Comment: please create a new blank js file, write "alert('loaded');" in it, save it and load this js file instead via getScript and tell me what happens please

Comment: Isn't there a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
// I loaded value between 901 to 1600 width, You can run with your min-width or max-width
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ // Or else use with your requirment function (ex.$(window).on('load') or click function etc.)
var windowsize = $(window).width();
if ((windowsize >= 901) && (windowsize <= 1600)) {
       //Do Your Code Here... 
}
});
```